# CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I trying open already created ASP.NET project in another PC locally via IIS manager. But I'm getting this error:

**CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

[image]

I've tried the following to resolve this:

1. Added Namespaces :

   ```
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

   CrystalDecisions.Shared;

   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;
   ```
2. Target Framework set to .Net Framework 4.
3. Installed CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine via NuGet Package manager.

Comment: Are the referenced assemblies in the `bin` folder of your ASP.NET web app?

Comment: In the bin folder is CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll

Comment: Have you added the reference to your references by right-clicking `References` in the project explorer and adding the required references?

Comment: Yes i already added the references.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Locate your C# project file ( YourProjectName.csproj ).
2. Open it using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.7.html) or any other text editor.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and find for `<Reference Include=`
4. There should be a CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
5. If it isn't add this, use the correct version:

   ```
   <Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
   <Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
   <Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
   <Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
   <Reference Include="FlashControlV71, Version=1.0.3187.32366, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I just faced this error while running a windows forms application in VS 2019 and below were the steps I took to resolve it:

- I checked the references node (In project explorer) and all the 4 CrystalDecision packages were there but with a yellow warning icon to all of them so I deleted them all.
- Then I opened the Nuget package manager to search for each of the packages starting from CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine. They were all marked as "installed" so I uninstalled and reinstalled them one after the other. And then I built the project successfully.
  This process removed the packages from the Packages.config file and added them back after installation.

What I noticed was just that the .Net framework version for the packages in the packages.config file was changed from net45 to net40.

So apparently, I have been referencing the wrong .Net version but I wouldn't have realized because the project was building fine before I switched to VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

I reopen the project folder by `File>Open>Web Site...` and save anoter solution, and the error missing.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same issue. So I realized that my project target framework had changed to 3.5 and I upgraded the framework to 4.5. It helped to resolve my issue.